# how to use ArcGIS cloud hosted map with custom data from mysql

Tags: mysql, markers, arcgis-online

I have map hosted on ArcGIS.com which I can use and embed in my webpage. I have few tables with latitude-longitude in mysql. is there anyway I can add it as marker overlay layer on map taken from ArcGIS.com ?

Note: My server does not support spatial tools like PostgreSQL and Geoserver. SO I am trying to find an alternative. any help and guidance will be appreciated.